# Quick and easy way to parse int from *char

Tags: c, string, parsing, numbers

I have the following String

```
char *filename = "/home/data/slice-10-1.dat";
```

I need to parse the following

```
int sliceTime
int sliceIndex;
```

`sliceTime` should be 10 and `sliceOrder` should be 1

Comment: Read more some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and look into [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/VOTtQK)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Why do you often post your good answers as comments? I saw that several times now with the same text <<like this>>. I mean it's very honorable from you not bagging for reputation but your answer is quite nice and may be overlooked as comment.

Comment: @AndreKampling There is an unclear point in this processing request.

Comment: Thanks guys..that was fast...I accepted the answer based on second option @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "/home/data/slice-10-1.dat";
  int sliceTime, sliceIndex, counter = 0;
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ./-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    //printf("%s\n" ,pch);
    size_t ln = strlen(pch) - 1;
    if( pch[ln] == '\n' ) pch[ln] = '\0';
    int notNumber = 0;
    /* Ensure that input is a number */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
      if( !isdigit(pch[i]) ) {
        notNumber = 1;
      }
    }
    if(!notNumber)
        if(counter++ == 0)
            sliceTime = atoi(pch);
        else
            sliceIndex = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ./-");
  }
  printf("SliceTime = %d, SliceIndex = %d\n", sliceTime, sliceIndex);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> SliceTime = 10, SliceIndex = 1

---

If you always have the same string pattern, use BLUEPIXY's solution, by using [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *filename = "/home/data/slice-10-1.dat";
    int sliceTime, sliceIndex;
    if(sscanf(filename, "%*[^-]-%d-%d", &sliceTime, &sliceIndex) == 2){
        printf("%d, %d\n", sliceTime, sliceIndex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 10, 1

Comment: I would go for the second option as I always have the same string pattern..

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtok()` to get the tokens and then use `atoi()` to convert string into intergers.